# NSTableView requesting Data too early

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I've run into a bit of an issue with NSTableView. The problem is that the table view is requesting data too early (it immediately requests the data from the controller), as in, the data is not there when the table view asks for it. Other methods, which gather the data to be shown in the table view haven't finished executing by the time NSTableView requests the data.

Hope that makes some kind of sense! I'm using Objective-C and doing mac dev (not iphone) btw.

Anyway, is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance.